# What does "Running Meteor from a checkout" as seen in meteor (mrt) console output actually mean?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have suddenly started getting the following message - all seems to work but i don't know why im getting it / what it really means for my app.
The only thing i can think of is that some smart-package im using is looking for an older version of meteor, and mrt is clever enough to not use a meteor version that will break it?

> Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
>
> Done installing smart packages
>
> Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!
>
> => **Running Meteor from a checkout -- overrides project version (0.6.2)**

The thing is i'm pretty sure i *want* to be running on 0.6.2 not overriding it to some other version.

So what does this mean really? - and what do i need to do to *not* get it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure why it uses that odd terminology. Version 0.6.0 introduced project versions, so each project could run its own version of meteor similar to how meteorite does with `smart.json`

What `Running Meteor from a checkout -- overrides project version (0.6.2)` means is this version is overridden by the version in your smart.json. Typically the latest version on the master branch on [github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor) (which is checked out hence the wording). So at this moment if you ran `mrt` it would use `0.6.2.1`

I'm sure over time meteorite will eventually be folded into meteor. 0.6.0 was just released a short while ago so some updates still need to be done to make them work better together.

Comment: Thanks - so if i refer to tag "release/0.6.2" in my smart.json i would achieve my desired result if i understand you.

Comment: Yes, that is you want it to run `0.6.2`. if you want the latest version whatever it is you can use `branch:"master"` (default) instead